# C# - Extracting clr.dll etc. of application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, clr

I'm trying to extract clr.dll and mscorwks.dll in an application from another software which is written in C#. My purpose is to collect all the files that are needed for a memory dump analysis, even if the analysis is to be done on an offline machine.

What I tried upto now is;

```
var currentAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(process.MainModule.FileName);//with the given process;
var assemblyList = currentAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().ToList();
var manifestList = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Though the `GetReferencedAssemblies()` doesn't give me clr.dll or mscorwks.dll but only mscorlib.dll and `GetManifestResourceNames()` give me just an image file that is used in the software.

Did anyone have such experience? Am I missing something to get the DLLs I want?

Thank you for your interest!

Regards,

Erdi

Comment: Well, not that way, these are unmanaged DLLs.  You'd need Process.Modules to see them, includes all the OS modules as well.  "Offline machine" is not practical, you need the PDBs and that requires using the symbol server.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you! :)

Comment: Though, I couldn't find mscorwks.dll there, any other place I should look for that?

Comment: You get clr.dll if your app targets .NET 4.0 and up, mscorwks.dll if it targets 3.5 or less.  Never both.

Comment: Alright, so the final list I need is;

clr.dll
mscordacwks.dll
sos.dll
mscordbi.dll

Can I obtain all by the same method? I gave that a try but it was no good. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to achieve what you want to do is to use `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime`(nuget-package) and it's `DataTarget`class. This lets you attach to a process and read about anything from the process.

For iterating all loaded modules (managed and unmanaged that is) you could then do:

```
    using (dt = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(proc.Id, 100, AttachFlag.Passive))
    {
        // since 4.0 we can possibly find more than one runtime (side-by-side CLRs) in one AppDomain...
        if (dt.ClrVersions.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var clr in dt.ClrVersions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(clr.Version + " " + clr.Flavor.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `proc`is an instance of `System.Diagnostics.Process`.
Instead of using the shortcut via `ClrVersions`you can also enumerate all modules (by calling `EnumerateModules`)